# Proper initialisation of smart pointers array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, initialization

For such case:

```
    class A
    {
        //implementation
    };

    class B
    {
     public:
         B();
        ~B();
     private:
         std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> _innerArray;
    };
```

what should I do in the `B()` to create an object with valid state? Do I need to manually call default constructor for every `A` object in array? And do I need to do something special in `~B()`? If B class is example of bad design, feel free to say how to make it better. Thanks.

**Edit**
So, here is a scheme of what I really need here.

[image]

So real values stored only in array of A and all other objects are for storing connections.
The easiest  example - A = dot, B = Line (or curve) going via selected dots and C = a plane described by lines. Hope it makes question more exact.

Comment: Sanity check: do you need the pointer here at all? And if so, should it be a shared pointer?

Comment: Class B is supposed to have access to but not own some objects stored somewhere else. I don't see using unique_ptr instead of shared_ptr making any sense here, but I am a noob to smart pointers.

Comment: @Pavel You’re right: your scenario precludes the use of `unique_ptr`, and it mandates the use of pointers. However, if `B` isn’t supposed to take ownership I’d even consider using raw pointers instead of shared pointers. After all, the latter denote *shared ownership* (but maybe that’s what you require after all).

Comment: @ПавелОганесян Do you intend for the lifetime of the pointed-at objects to be extended if they are contained in an instance of your class? If yes, then `shared_ptr` looks OK. Otherwise you could hold raw pointers.

Comment: You should consider passing "somewhere else" as a parameter to the constructor of `B` and use the iterator version of `std::vector` constructor to initialize `_innerArray`, see my answer below. If `B` should not own the objects, weak pointers may be considered instead of shared pointers. I do not see a reason for using raw pointers.

Comment: @KonradRudolph an alternative would be to use a `weak_ptr`, which is non-owning but prevents an instance of `B` having invalid raw pointers. This would be the better way to do this, unless it was _guaranteed_ that the lifetime of an instance of `B` was _always_ shorter than the lifetime of any instance of `A` that it contains.

Comment: @Rook `weak_ptr` is only appropriate if the pointer is owned by a `shared_ptr`, which restricts its usefulness. Its purpose is essentially to break cycles in circular object graphs. If that’s the case here – fine.

Comment: @KonradRudolph sure, but the resource is wrapped in a `shared_ptr` instance; the OP's question says as much. The use of a `weak_ptr` does extend beyond breaking cyclic reference graphs, and a non-owning smart pointer is one such additional use.

Comment: I added a scheme to question to make it clearly. Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a `B` object in a valid state you do not have to do anything more. You even do not have to declare and implement constructor and destructor for `B`. `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>` that is a member of `B` will be default initialized in `B`'s constructor which means it will not have any elements in a container yet. It will also be properly deleted in `~B` thanks to `std::vector` and `std::shared_ptr` destructors.

On the other hand if you for example want to initialize it somehow (i.e. 3 values) you can use `std::vector`'s `std::initializer_list` constructor in a `B`'s constructor initialization list. For example:

```
class B
{
 public:
     B(): _innerArray{ std::make_shared<A>(),
                       std::make_shared<A>(),
                       std::make_shared<A>() } {}
    ~B() {}
 private:
     std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> _innerArray;
};
```

Remember that `std::make_shared` uses perfect forwarding so you pass `A`'s constructor arguments as the function arguments and not the class object itself.

Answering your concerns about the design I would like to encourage you to first think about the exclusive ownership of members in a vector before you decide to share them.

```
class B
{
 public:
     B();
    ~B();
 private:
     std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> _innerArray;
};
```

Above implementation is more effective on many grounds. First of all it makes your design more clear on who is responsible for the lifetime of `A`s. Next `std::unique_ptr` is faster because it does not demand thread safe reference counting. And last but not least it does not cost any additional memory (compared to regular C pointer) while `std::shared_ptr` may take tens of bytes (24-48) to store shared state data which is highly ineffective when you operate on small classes. That is why I always use `std::unique_ptr` as my first resort smart pointer and I only fallback to `std::shared_ptr` when it is really needed.

**EDIT:**

Answering your edit I would create 3 containers of classes `A`, `B`, `C`. Depending of the fact if you need them to be polymorphic or not I would store either values like that (non-polymorphic types):

```
std::deque<A> as;
std::deque<B> bs;
std::deque<C> cs;
```

or (polymorphic types):

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> as;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> bs;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<C>> cs;
```

in that order (`as` must live longer than `bs` and `bs` must live longer than `cs`). Then I would just have `std::vector<A*>` inside `B` class and `std::vector<B*>` inside `C` class without any smart pointers usage.

I hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

Changed `std::vector` to `std::deque` in the first case which allows references/pointers to container elements survive containers extensions with `push_back()`. However they will not survive erasing elements, sorting or other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you do it like that, the vector has a size of zero elements, i.e. the contents are trivially properly initialized. If the vector were of positive size (e.g. after calling `resize` on the vector), each of the elements would be properly initialized. Since the elements are `shared_ptr`s, the default constructor of `shared_ptr` would be called, which means that you would end up with a vector of empty pointers.

If you want to copy the contents from another container, use the iterator version of the vector constructor:

```
B (SomeContainerTypeContainingSharedPointers container)
: _innerArray (container.begin (), container.end () ) {
}
```

If you do not want to initialize the vector from a container, but from somewhere else (e.g. create the objects on the fly) -- write an input iterator type yourself (i.e. kind of a "factory iterator").

Answer (score 1):

The vector is empty so you don't have to do anything special in the default constructor. And you don't need to do anything in `B()` either. The reference count of the `shared_ptrs` will be decreased automatically when the vector's destructor is called.

Answer (score 1):

Bt default `std::shared_ptr<A>` will populate inner ptr with `NULL`. To create smart pointer use `std::make_shared`:

```
_innerArray.push_back(std::make_shared<A>(/*constructor params here*/));
```

But in your example vector is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor already does everything needed. You can even leave `B()` out without any loss.